# Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в таблице выводятся системные данные таблицы?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в таблице выводятся системные данные таблицы?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// использование метода GetSchemaTable для получения информации о схеме таблицы к которой обращается объект DataReader


namespace SomeName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True;"; // создание строки подключения

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", connection);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable(); //получение информации о схеме таблицы Customers

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows) // вывод на экран информации, предоставляемой методом GetSchemaTable
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", column.ColumnName, row[column]);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: Обычные табличные данные

Comment: Что вы понимаете под обычными табличными данными?

Comment: Вы же сами запросили _схему_. Вот данные схемы таблицы и получили.

Comment: Это метаданные или это искусственно заданные имена столбцов с содержимым?